# Sharing usercontrols and classes under solution

Tags: vb.net

I have `VB.NET` solution with few projects.
Also I have several common user controls and classes which are used in all those projects.
For now I include those classes "as a link".
But if I copy controls from one form to another those (linked) controls are not copied while generic .NET controls ARE copied well.

Is there any place under "solution" where I can put such code to be common for all project included?

Comment: Why don't you create another project in your solution with your custom controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might create another project (something like [xxx].Dependencies or [xxx].Controls or [xxx].Utils) and all the rest of projects refer to it.

this will also make your common controls/utility classes separated from your main project: easier for writing test cases, as well as much more reusable for future projects.